# In what order do .NET Windows forms events fire?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms

I notice that there are a number of different events I can capture when I'm working with a Windows Form in .NET (or any other control, for that matter) - on opening, there's:

- Load
- Activated
- Shown
- VisibleChanged

And when closing, there's:

- Leave
- FormClosed
- FormClosing
- Disposed

Plus any others I've missed. I know I could put a messagebox in each event, and then run my application and write down the order, but I doubt I'll remember it.

**Is there a reference online that lists the *-order-* in which these events occur**, for Forms and other controls? I can't find it on MSDN, though maybe I've missed it somewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one of the relevant pages on MSDN :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx

Comment: Wow - my Google skills are weak. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 8):

This is also called the lifecycle of win-forms applications. Every .net technology has a document on these.

Winforms - http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2007/01/08/windows-forms-event-lifecycle.aspx

Form Startup

1. OnHandleCreated
2. OnCreateControl
3. OnLoad
4. OnActivated
5. OnShown

Form Shutdown

1. OnClosing
2. OnClosed
3. OnDeactivate
4. OnHandleDestroyed

Comment: +1 for mentioning "lifecycle" - knowing the magic keyword is a huge help when searching

Comment: I have found that in special cases can Onload be called before OnCreateControl. This case is Contorl.CreateGraphics().

Answer (score 2):

**Showing a form:**

1. Control.HandleCreated
2. Control.BindingContextChanged
3. Form.Load
4. Control.VisibleChanged
5. Control.GotFocus
6. Form.Activated
7. Form.Shown

**Closing a form:**

1. Form.Closing
2. Form.FormClosing
3. Form.Closed
4. Form.FormClosed
5. Form.Deactivate
6. Control.LostFocus
7. Control.HandleDestroyed
8. Component.Disposed

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this behavior, may have something to do with MDI:

```
form.Focus(); // calls OnHandleCreated (this.Handle is x)
form.Show( ); // calls OnLoad (this.Handle is still x), then OnHandleCreated (this.Handle is y)
```