# Form changes size between constructor exit and begining of Load C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am rather baffled at the moment, I have a form which I show as a dialog (although non dialog is the same) in response to a menu item click.

```
    var createUser = new FrmCreateUser();
    createUser.ShowDialog();
```

Somewhere between the constructor exiting, and when the load event is fired the size is being changed.

I have overloaded WndProc in the 'parent' form, although it just falls though to the base implementation so I find it hard to believe that's the cause.

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == (int)WindowsMessages.WM_SYSCOMMAND)
        {

            if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == (int)WindowsMessages.SC_MINIMIZE)
            {
                foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
                    if (f != this)
                        f.Hide();

            }
            else if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == (int)WindowsMessages.SC_RESTORE)
            {
                foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
                    if (f != this && f.GetType() != typeof (Controls.DockLocation) )
                        f.Show();
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

I can restore the size to what is should be in the load event handler, but I remain confused as to the cause.

```
    private void FrmCreateUser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Size = new Size(RestoreBounds.Width, RestoreBounds.Height);
    }
```

If anyone can shed some light on this it would be much appreciated.

---

**Edit**

Removing the WndProc override has no effect.

SizeChanged is only invoked once (inside the `createUser.ShowDialog()` call) which occurs before `OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)` is called.

**Edit 2**

Here are some pictures to show the effect.

designer:

[Designer http://www.free.nodespot.com/designer.jpg](http://www.free.nodespot.com/designer.jpg)

runtime:
[Runtime http://www.free.nodespot.com/runtime.jpg](http://www.free.nodespot.com/runtime.jpg)

Comment: I would suggest turning off the WndProc on the parent to confirm if this is part of the problem, then continue to 'strip down' the app until you have a clearer idea of what's causing it.

Comment: There's a list of the events being fired in the Form class at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575508/in-what-order-do-net-windows-forms-events-fire/1575573#1575573. Maybe that can be of help examining the problem.

Comment: You could also go the other way around: use the WndProc to detect when the size is changed (after base.WndProc has executed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it - much by a happy fluke of where the PropertyGrid positioned itself as to anything else. `StartPosition` had been set to `WindowsDefaulBounds` rather than the default of `WindowsDefaultLocation`.