# Order between OnHandleCreated and OnLoad

Tags: c#, winforms, readonly

On a windows form, is there a guaranteed firing order between these, does anyone know? This is on .NET v2.
It appears to be the former(sorry) first.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575508

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**`OnHandleCreated` comes first.**

[From the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx):

> The Form and Control classes expose a set of events related to application startup and shutdown. When a Windows Forms application starts, the startup events of the main form are raised in the following order:
>
> Control.HandleCreated
>
> Control.BindingContextChanged
>
> Form.Load
>
> Control.VisibleChanged
>
> Form.Activated
>
> Form.Shown

Comment: Ah thanks, was looking at the OnLoad/OnHandleCreated pages which are pretty useless.